'void' type not allowed here int s = solve(a, n-1) + solve(a, n-2);
When I Code this:
public class Solution {
    public static int[] generateFibonacciNumbers(int n) {
        // Write your code here.
        int[] a = new int[n];
        solve(a, n);

        return a;
    }

    public static void solve(int a[], int n){
        if(n<=1){
            a[n] = n;
            return;
        }

        int s = solve(a, n-1) + solve(a, n-2);
        a[n] = s;
    }
}

I get this output:
Compilation Failed
./Solution.java:16: error: 'void' type not allowed here
        int s = solve(a, n-1) + solve(a, n-2);
                     ^
./Solution.java:16: error: 'void' type not allowed here
        int s = solve(a, n-1) + solve(a, n-2);
                                     ^
2 errors

I don't know how to start asking about this other than to ask:

What went wrong here?
What does this error message mean?


fyi you can find the nth fibonacci number in O(log n) time using this simple algorithm https://stackoverflow.com/a/32273141/256196 (code there is C, but Java being "C like" makes it very easy to convert to Java)

void is nothing. you cant add the output of nothing and nothing

It seems like the issue lies in trying to add each result from a void function without a return type to an int.
You need to change the return type of solved to int
